# Cancelar la ejecución bucle infinito en Python (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, bucles, vscode

Empecé a programar hace unas semanas en Python con Sublime Text 3 y no tuve ningún problema, sin embargo hace poco al pasarme a Visual Studio Code me topé con un problema bastante molesto...

Al ejecutar un bucle infinito como podría ser:

```
while True:
    print("hola")
```

No encuentro a dónde debo de darle para poder cancelar el programa. En Sublime había un lugar donde decía: "End task", pero en Visual Studio Code no he encontrado nada similar. Por ahora lo que hago es cerrar Visual Studio Code y volver a abrirlo pero me parece muy poco práctico.

¿Sabéis a dónde debo de darle para parar el programa? ¡Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Comment: Depende de como corras el programa. Si lo haces mediante una terminar presionas `crrl+c` y si usas alguna extensión deberás buscar.

Comment: Necesitamos más información para poder ayudarte. No sabemos cómo lo estás ejecutando.

Comment: Puedes correrlo en la pestaña de `Run and Debug` (Ctrl + Shift + D) y en ese caso si te ofrecerá un botón rojo para parar la ejecución. Si lo ejecutas directamente desde la consola se detiene con Ctrl + C.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución.

1. darle sobre el terminal
2. darle a "Kill".

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ejecutes el programa en la terminal de visual studio code
En la esquina superior derecha del mismo terminal aparecera un icono de papelera ("Terminar el terminal":(si lo tienes en español))
le das click y listo